# Servo motor doesn't respond

Tags: c, pwm, servo

I'm trying to "steer" my servo by using pwm. To make my code better, I refactor the FILE type out of the function so that the file is not being opened and closed with every call I make. But this refactor has gone wrong. It doesn't throw an exception or something....

```
#include "pwm_control.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static FILE *pwm_file;

void export_pwm(void) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(PWM_PATH "export", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening enable file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(file, "0");
    fclose(file);
}

void enable_pwm(void) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(PWM_PATH "pwm0/enable", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening enable file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(file, "1");
    fclose(file);
}

void disable_pwm(void) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(PWM_PATH "pwm0/enable", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening enable file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(file, "0");
    fclose(file);
}

void init_duty_cycle_file(void) {
    pwm_file = fopen(PWM_PATH "pwm0/duty_cycle", "w");
}

void close_duty_cyle_file(void) {
    fclose(pwm_file);
}

void set_pwm_duty_cycle(int duty_cycle) {
    if (pwm_file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening duty_cycle file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(pwm_file, "%d", duty_cycle * 10000);
}

void set_pwm_period() {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(PWM_PATH "pwm0/period", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening period file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(file, "%d", PERIOD);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Try after `fclose(pwm_file);` adding `pwm_file = NULL` because another function tests that with `if (pwm_file == NULL)` and if it isn't, will unhappily write to the closed file.

Comment: added it but the servo still doesn't work...

Comment: How could it have worked as local `static` when the `FILE*` variable is needed in other functions? Was it defined in a function you didn't post, and then passed as an argument?

Comment: First the file was declared in the function itself (set_pwm_duty_cycle). So first in the function I created a new file wrote the content and close it. But everytime i use the function it creates a complete new file pointer then. So i was thinking of splitting it up...

Comment: Re "*It doesn't throw an exception or something....*", uh, C doesn't have exceptions

Comment: The answer is obviously: The file handle isn't opened, or it's unrelated to the file handle at all and we have no way of knowing what it is.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are doing from the partial code posted. It doesn't matter if you call separate functions to open, write and close, or all in one function. It still creates  a new pointer each time the file is opened, regardless of where it is defined. Why do think a global file pointer makes better code?

Comment: Are you sure your PWM code is working? Rather than jump right to servo control, perhaps configure your code to output the current duty-cycle to verify it is doing what you intent. Then configure it to drive an a simple LED with current-limiting resistor to verify you are getting your PWM signal to your circuitry. Then add the servo and controller. Those are just thoughts based on past experience, you are free to do it any way you like. Also adding board/hardware details will help others understand better what you are attempting.

Comment: A) if i define the pwm_file pointer inside set_pwm_duty_cycle ... then it is working. For god sake i see the servo turning to the right angle. It is not like the holy mother is turning it over.... @WeatherVane but that is what i want to achieve that i don't have to open the file and close the file each time that i want to write value to it. Because the servo gets continue values and it needs to rotate constantly